# Mouse selection and copy is not working when i tried to copy the contents of the data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to make a selection through mouse and copy the contents on the data table(inside the tbody).
But the selection itself seems disabled and is not highlighting the selection that i have made, so its obvious that i am not able to copy the selected part.
Can anyone tell me why and how to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Its because of this CSS - **user-select : none**
It disables the user select over the HTML element on which its written.
If you want to make selection possible use **user-select : all**.

Available options are:

1. user-select: none;
2. user-select: auto;
3. user-select: text;
4. user-select: contain;
5. user-select: all;

Reference link: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

Comment: i have not used any css before and now even if i add this also it is not taking.I tried changing the bootstrap.css and jquery drag also but it did not  work.:(
Any other solution!

Comment: don't try doing it in debugger, it wont be applied, I don't know y?
Apply this particular CSS in the source code , and then run the application, then only it will be applied. Just try once.

Comment: i have put this in the table.css file for the whole body like:
#tableid tbody {
user-select: all;
}
but still it is not working.
See if anything else has to done to the above code

Comment: Can you check in debugger tools, if this particular css is getting applies or not?

Comment: and in browser you are running your application

Comment: Add the below CSS
       { -webkit-user-select: none ;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;}